# Parse findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock crashes during query

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I know this is a very simple problem, but I have been stuck on it for 3 days so I am now reaching out for help. I am trying to run a query in Parse, but it seems like the query itself is causing my app to crash.

```
print(self.topUsersArray.objectAtIndex(sender3.tag))

        let checkIfAlreadyFollowing = PFQuery(className: "relation")
        checkIfAlreadyFollowing.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
        checkIfAlreadyFollowing.whereKey("followed", equalTo: self.topUsersArray.objectAtIndex(sender3.tag))
        checkIfAlreadyFollowing.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects, error) -> Void in

}
```

It continues to crash at the `findObjectsInBackground` line. This makes no sense to me because I know for a fact that there are valid objects in place for the `whereKey("", equalTo: )` constraints. And even if they weren't valid, why would the query just return nil instead of crashing.

The error is `objectAtIndex 0 beyond bounds` and it crashes on the `findObjectsInBackGround` line.

Note. I have even commented out the second query constraint and put a breakpoint after the `-> Void in` and it still crashes.

Comment: Its crashing because of this: self.topUsersArray.objectAtIndex(sender3.tag), Can you log the value of the array elements  or count of elements in topUsersArray before using it in query, and let me know.

Comment: Just FYI parse is shutting down on 28th Jan 2017. Check this : http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: It is not crashing because of self.topUsersArray.objectAtIndex(sender3.tag). I am able to print that object out before running the query as I show above in the code. Also I have commented out both of my query constraints and it still continues to crash. Also I have already migrated off of Parse. I plan to continue using their SDK though.

Comment: What really does not makes sense to me is that when I comment out both lines it should just gather all the objects from the 'relation' class. I do this at several other points within this viewController.

Comment: @Chandan005 I dont understand people pointing out that parse is shutting down, they open sourced the server and you can very easily install it on your own hardware and everything is working the same... dont you think that people that develop in Parse.com already knows that? It pop up like everytime you login to parse.com